# Julia Union of Composite Types: `convert` has no method matching convert

Tags: types, julia

I'm trying to do a Union between two composite types that I've created:

```
type point
   x::Int8
   y::Int8
end

type vector
    x::Int8
    y::Int8
end

VecOrPoint = Union{point,vector}

x = point(Int8(2),Int8(3))
y = vector(Int8(2),Int8(3))

function sum(u::VecOrPoint,v::VecOrPoint)
  return  VecOrPoint(u.x + v.x,u.y + v.y) # ERROR HERE
end


z = sum(x,y)
```

And i'm getting the folowing error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching    

convert(::Type{Union{point,vector}}, ::Int8, ::Int8)

This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Union{point,vector}  (...),

since type constructors fall back to convert methods.

Closest candidates are:
call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
convert{T}(::Type{T}, !Matched::T)

in sum at /home/renatinho/periodoAtual/recsys/testeJulia.jl:17

while loading /home/renatinho/periodoAtual/recsys/testeJulia.jl, in 

expression starting on line 20
```

I've serched on Google but i cannot figure out anything

Comment: This is not what you want to be doing. Using unions like this leads to bad performance anyways. You should probably try to use a parametric type or dispatch instead.

Comment: For more help, you may want to check out the [Gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia). You're off on the wrong track and I think a chat is a better way to find out what you want to do and how you'd get there.

Comment: In order to construct a concrete type, use `return  typeof(u)(u.x + v.x,u.y + v.y)` instead - if it OK to use the type of `u` for the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Julia [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#type-unions)

> A type union is a special abstract type

and from [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#abstract-types):

> Abstract types cannot be instantiated

Thus, what you are trying to do is not possible.  (when you call `VecOrPoint()` in your function, you are trying to create an instantiation, i.e. trying to create an object whose type is your union of types).

I also don't really understand the purpose behind what you are trying to do.  What could it mean to "convert" something to a union of types, when the types within that union are different?  (In your example you give, the two types are identical, so I suppose it could be possible in that very limited sense, but it also wouldn't make any sense to have two identical types like that and then take the union of them).

If you wanted to accomplish something along those lines, you could perhaps write yourself a new `Myconvert()` function (or possibly overload the existing `convert` function).  In your new function, you could perform some logic on the input, and based on that, convert it to one or the other of your types.  Your new function then could sensibly take as an input your union of types.

Edit: or, as Chris suggests in comments, use a type dispatch.  See also Dan's comment to original post for another useful idea.

Comment: It looks like he wants to build a vector by adding points to it, and it feels like hes trying emulate some object oriented way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, Michael Ohlrogge. I made this code after read about Unions on a book, the code was based on an example that I read on the book, just for test.

Comment: The problem here is not really due to the fact that abstract types can't have instances. It is possible to define a conversion to a union type, and that conversion could for example just choose to return  a `point`. The real problem is that this is a weird thing to do, like ordering "vanilla or chocolate". Usually you pick one and order something specific.